# Failing on create_engine while using SQLAlchemy on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to deploy a Flask application which uses SQLAlchemy to an AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment.  I can deploy and see a running application, but when I attempt to use create_engine to connect to my database the whole thing crashes.  I can run the run the whole app locally on a linux vm (including using the database within the ElasticBeanstalk environment.)  I can ssh into the app server and print to the terminal.

I think something about how the application runs when being accessed from a browser (via the application url) is causing the problem.  I would be immensely grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.  I've been working on this problem for 3 days and I'm starting to go nuts.

This is the code I am using to create my session:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

import settings

Base = declarative_base()

# establish connection to database
def db_connect():
    """
    Performs database connection using database settings from settings.py.
    Returns sqlalchemy engine instance
    """
    print ".............................................."
    print "...Connecting to Database at URL : "
    print "...attempting URL(**settings.DATABASE)"
    print "... ", URL(**settings.DATABASE)
    print "...above should read: "
    print "... postgresql://ebroot:42Snails@aa12jlddfw2awrj.cc6p0ojvcx3g.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/ebdb"
    print ".............................................."
    print "...attempting engine = create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))..."
    try:
        engine = create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
        print "...Succeeded in creating engine.................."
        return engine
    except:
        print "..................................................."
        print "...Failed to create engine in database_setup.py...."
        print "..................................................."
        raise   

def makeSession():
    # Establishes a session called session which allows you to work with the DB
    try:
        print "....trying to create session.................."
        engine = db_connect()
        print "....succeeded in db_connect().................."
        Base.metadata.bind = engine
        print "....succeeded in Base.metadata.bind = engine..."
    # create a configured "Session" class
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        print "....succeeded in Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)..."
    # create a Session
        session = Session()
        print ".............................................."
        print "...Succeeded in creating session.............."
        print ".............................................."
        return session
    except:
        print "................................................."
        print "...Failed to create session in application.py...."
        print "................................................."
        raise   
        print "finally.... session.close()"
        session.close()
```

This is a snippet from /var/log/httpd/error_log.  Lines beggining with "..." are print statements I am using to isolate the issue.  I have altered the url I use to get to the database to frustrate the robots.  The address I use works perfectly from my local machine and from the terminal when I ssh into the app server.

```
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:00.159375 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 670] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.259575 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1077] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.270801 2016] [so:warn] [pid 1077] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.273963 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1077] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.274662 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1077] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.274712 2016] [:warn] [pid 1077] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9.
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.274719 2016] [:warn] [pid 1077] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.10.
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.276674 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1077] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:01.276690 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1077] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Mar 19 20:16:04.069713 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...in settings.py.......
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419659 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ....trying to create session..................
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419702 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ..............................................
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419707 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...Connecting to Database at URL : 
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419711 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...attempting URL(**settings.DATABASE)
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419876 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...  postgresql://user:password@aa12jlddfw2awrj.cc6p9990ojvcx3g.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/ebdb
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419884 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...above should read: 
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419889 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ... postgresql://user:password@aa12jlddfw2awrj.cc6p9990ojvcx3g.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/ebdb
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419893 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ..............................................
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.419897 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...attempting engine = create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))...
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.427168 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...................................................
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.427189 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...Failed to create engine in database_setup.py....
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.427193 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...................................................
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.427200 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] .................................................
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.427203 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] ...Failed to create session in application.py....
[Sat Mar 19 20:19:53.427206 2016] [:error] [pid 1080] .................................................
```

Here is the url for the running app:
http://keirseysorterapp.9yk6hymk2z.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/testApp

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get this to work.  I ended up following this tutorial: 
https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80#.t2lbbv5q3

The tutorial uses the Flask-SQLAlchemy module instead of importing Flask and SQLAlchemy separately.  Once I used this method I had no problems.  Good luck!